# Failed to update nuget Package

Tags: nuget

I tried to run `Update-Package -reinstall Owin`

I'm getting the below output for a failed installation.

```
Package 'Owin.1.0.0' already exists in folder 'G:\gitlab\CompanyWebsite\packages'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Owin 1.0.0' does not exist in project 'CompanyWebsite
Package 'Owin 1.0' already exists in folder 'G:\gitlab\CompanyWebsite\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 1.04 sec
```

**What could be the problem?**

Notice the version "1.0.0" vs the "1.0" by any chance the package developer reset their numbering format?

I managed to install the package by

1. Delete the package in the /packages/Owin1.0 folder
2. Make sure Owin is not listed in package.config
3. Run command - Install-Package Owin

But why reinstall does not work at the first place. Trying to learn to better understand here.

Comment: have you tried using the "Manage NuGet Packages" UI, to see if it gives more information?

Comment: @zivkan I did BUT nothing new on the UI (no messages, prompts etc)